# How can I bring GDELT Google big query results to C#?

Tags: c#, sql, google-bigquery

I want to run some simple queries on GDELT Google big query dataset available here:

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/gdelt-bq:full.events

The queries are for example:

```
SELECT   year, 
         actor1name, 
         actor2name, 
         count 
FROM     ( 
                  SELECT   actor1name, 
                           actor2name, 
                           year, 
                           Count(*)                                           count, 
                           Rank() OVER(partition BY year ORDER BY count DESC) rank 
                  FROM     ( 
                                  SELECT actor1name, 
                                         actor2name, 
                                         year 
                                  FROM   [gdelt-bq:full.events] 
                                  WHERE  actor1name < actor2name 
                                  AND    actor1countrycode != '' 
                                  AND    actor2countrycode != '' 
                                  AND    actor1countrycode!=actor2countrycode), 
                           ( 
                                  SELECT actor2name actor1name, 
                                         actor1name actor2name, 
                                         year 
                                  FROM   [gdelt-bq:full.events] 
                                  WHERE  actor1name > actor2name 
                                  AND    actor1countrycode != '' 
                                  AND    actor2countrycode != '' 
                                  AND    actor1countrycode!=actor2countrycode), 
                  where    Actor1Name is NOT NULL 
                  AND      actor2name IS NOT NULL GROUP each BY 1, 
                           2, 
                           3 
                  HAVING   count > 100 ) 
WHERE    rank=1 
ORDER BY year
```

When I run this in the query box in Google big query (through copying and pasting and the link above), I get the results and everything is fine. Now my problem is that I need to use these results in C#, say simply print the years and countries to console.

I found some examples here but I know very very little C#. Can somebody please tell me what to do from scratch to get these results printed?

Comment: Try googling: "read and output from database in c#"

Comment: I've not used the API library for dotnet personally, but https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started may help with your integration task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not trying to steal the answer from "[shollyman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212435/shollyman)", I just want it to be in an answer and not an actual comment, so here goes :

You can use the API library for dotnet [here](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started). This will let you do calls from C# directly into your app to the BigQuery API to get your response, which you can then read and use in your C#.